# Using iteration and sets to rewrite lists (deleting entries based on condition)

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, iteration

I'm trying to remove elements in a list (the list is of dimension seven at the moment) if any sub element is empty.  i.e given this simpler example list:

```
'car','doug','' 
dede,eli,fred 
'law', '','frank' 
'','roger','w'
alex,berk,carl
```

After deleting any row with a "blank" (or another condition at some point)

```
dede,eli,fred
alex,berk, carl
```

so far I've done something to this effect (it works!) for my list which has 7 elements using sets

```
list1=[item for item in list1 if item [0]!= '']
list1=[item for item in list1 if item [1]!= '']
list1=[item for item in list1 if item [2]!= '']
list1=[item for item in list1 if item [3]!= '']
list1=[item for item in list1 if item [4]!= '']
list1=[item for item in list1 if item [5]!= '']
list1=[item for item in list1 if item [6]!= '']
```

I've attempted something similar to the following. I'm not sure how to pass a list to a function properly in this context-but here x is a list

```
def empty(x):
    x=list(x)
    # the range should be updated to the column length here
    # i've left it at 7 for illustration
    for i in range(7):
        x=x[for item in x if item [i]!='']
    return x
```

Comment: Try `[item for item in list1 if '' not in list1]`

Comment: thanks-i'll try it now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using some python builtins [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
 x = [
    ['car','doug',''], 
    ['dede', 'eli', 'fred'], 
    ['law', '','frank'], 
    ['','roger','w'], 
    ['alex', 'berk' , 'carl']
]

# python 2.7
print filter(all, x)

# python 3.5
print(list(filter(all, x)))

- [['dede', 'eli', 'fred'], ['alex', 'berk', 'carl']]
```

Filter evaluates a preedicate and only returns it if it is true

---

All returns true if all items in an iterator are true

Comment: i'll try it!  to make sure I'm understanding it though-the all function returns an "empty"  entry as false though-correct?

Comment: yes in python empty strings are evaluated to False: try it yourself: `print(bool(''))`